# Designing a Database to store pages data

Tags: database, relational

I’m having a trouble with the design of a relational database.

I know how to design a relational database to store “resources”, I mean products, users, posts, comments, etc.

My problem is to design a relational database for modifiable pages. Which is the best way to design one to make modifiable by the client every page of a website? In example, I have an “Our products” page which have a list of products but also have a title, a text and an image which the client needs to modify frequently. The same for some extra pages which have different layouts (this mean they will all have a different number and type of fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can put a wsyiwyg editor to a page and store that html in a db table and whenever pages needs to be modified just load editor with the html from the db table and save it again after its modified.